# Modal dialog / replacement for RadWindow in jquery?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to open a pop-up style page.
 I would love to see any examples people might have.

In RadWindow I would do something like this:

```
    RadWindow statusWindow = new RadWindow();
    statusWindow.NavigateUrl = "./StatusWindow.aspx" + qs;
    statusWindow.ID = "sendWindow";
    statusWindow.Visible = true;
    statusWindow.Height = Unit.Pixel(180);
    statusWindow.Width = Unit.Pixel(595);
    statusWindow.Modal = true;
```

Comment: Hopefully not, that thing is *awful*. Anyway the generic term is *"modal dialog"*, of which there *are* jQuery extensions for... like jQuery Modal (go figure). RadWindow can operate in different "modes" as well so it might be useful to first define the "mode" desired.

Comment: (RadWindow is not *terribly* awful, but it failed in my use-case and my complaints are fueled with ASP.NET WebForm/UpdatePanel issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open` like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.focus();
```

Be aware however that unless your window is being opened directly as the result of a user action (click, etc.) it will likely be blocked as a popup in most browsers.

---

Edit: If you want to completely cover the main page, you can do something like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open();
myWindow.focus();
```

Comment: i need to mask main page can do the same in jquery?

Comment: but it is comming in new window. it should come in same page like a popup and it should mask the main page

Comment: A RadWindow is a "modal dialog", not a new browser window.